# SAS: Calculating(add, subtract, multipy, divide) values in a dataset

Tags: sas, addition

I would like to calculate values in a dataset. So if my dataset looks like

```
obs  x   y
1   10  100
2   20  200
3   30  300
4   40  400
```

I would like to create a new dataset that calculates only the first and last row of values in the original dataset. So for column x, I would like to add 10+40=50, and for column y, I would like to add 100+400=500. So my output dataset looks like

```
     x   y
sum  50  500
```

I am not sure how to extract specific cells from the dataset and sum(or multiply) them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What programming language / background are you coming to SAS from ?  What syntax would you use in that ?  Certain statistics are often calculated by coding a `Proc MEANS` step, however product of values is not one of those.  For special computation you would use a `DATA` step and collect values (in variables or array elements) as necessary for the computation at the last row of a group or data set.  A `DATA` step can have features and processing rules that don't align with your current coding experiences.

Comment: I only have a little experience in Python, so in python, I will use square brackets[] and colons: to grab entire rows or columns, but I wasn't sure how to do that in SAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `_N_=1` condition to identify the first row of data being read with a `SET` statement.  Additionally the `END=` option is used to test for last row.  Store the values from the first row in retained variables that will be used in the computation performed when the last row is read.

Example:

```
data have;
    input x   y;
    datalines;
10  100
20  200
30  300
40  400
;

data want(keep=x y label='Sum from values in first and last row of have');
    set have end=lastrow_flag;

    retain x_firstrow y_firstrow;

    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        x_firstrow=x; 
        y_firstrow=y; 
    end;

    if lastrow_flag then do;
        x = sum (x_firstrow, x);
        y = sum (y_firstrow, y);
        OUTPUT;
    end;
run;
```

[image]

Pro Tip:

If you are running PC SAS (Display Manager) you can program LOG window keys to perform custom commands (Use KEYS command to enter the command).  I always program `CTL RMB` as `VT &SYSLAST` so that *Control-Right mouse button* whilst hovering over LOG window will raise the ViewTable Viewer for the last created data set.

[image]